# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor page return Page with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 for creating an identity server. I use the Asp Identity and I scaffolded the login and register pages.

I have the following page:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
 ......
 public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
 ......
 public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
 {
     ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
 }
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
 {
     returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
     }

     return Page();
}
```

The cshtml contains:

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
......
<form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
......
```

**Behaviour:**
I land on the page on this link:
  https://localhost:5028/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=testlink
, so the ReturnUrl gets set to "testlink" in the OnGet() and is passed on to the form.

1. Correct: If I create a user with no validation errors (ModelState is valid), then LocalRedirect(returnurl) gets called with "testlink".
2. Wrong: If I create a user with validation errors (ModelState is invalid), then return Page() gets called. The issue is that in this case, the page is generated with empty model (@Model.ReturnUrl is null). The user sees the validation errors in the form, corrects them, but when he submits the form, he won't get redirected to "testlink" because it was lost.

**My question:** With what do I replace "*return Page();*" so that I can correct behaviour described on case 2? I tried "*return LocalRedirect("/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=" + returnUrl)*", but that refreshes the page (clears user input and doesn't show validation error messages).

Thank you!

Comment: Set the `ReturnUrl` property on POST

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `ReturnUrl` property on POST so it is available when the page reloads.

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string returnUrl = null) {
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    //...if we get this far something went wrong.
    //reset properties on model so they appear when page reloads
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before return Page(); call OnGet();

OnGet(your url);
return Page();

Comment: Wrong approach. We want to processd data from a post action not get.

Comment: While the wrong solution for the question posed, it did solve a problem for me of .Net failing to call OnGet when i was returning Page() with an error message (that needed OnGet logic to be invoked). I had no idea that return Page() did not implicitly invoke OnGet(). So I guess it just informs the browser to refresh w/o hitting the backend?